# Multidimensional Array Error?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array in VBA that is giving me

> error 9: 'Subscript out of range'

while looping through the array. I know what's causing the issue, but I'm unsure as to how to fix it. I'm checking if the values in two cells are the same. If they are, it adds that number to the loop counter before looping back through.

The issue is that the value being checked against is sometimes larger than the upper bound of the array. The array has 33 rows, so if the counter is at 32 and it tries to check if the row 5 below it (@ 37) is the same, it causes the issue.

Please find my code below.

```
Sub testing()
Dim d1 As Long
Dim d2 As Long
Dim ReportContents() As Variant

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim ReportContents(d1, d2)
ReportContents() = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BL" & lastrow).Value2


For d1 = 2 To UBound(ReportContents)
    Select Case True
        Case ReportContents(d1, 5) = ReportContents(d1 + 5, 5)
            Debug.Print "5! " & ReportContents(d1, 5).Value2
            d1 = d1 + 5
        Case ReportContents(d1, 5) = ReportContents(d1 + 4, 5)
            Debug.Print "4! " & ReportContents(d1, 5)
            d1 = d1 + 4

    End Select

Next d1
```

Comment: Then just loop to `UBound(ReportContents) -5`

Comment: Scott's suggestion is probably the answer you need. Just to add couple of things that might help the code: Don't think you need to ReDim your `ReportContents`. Also, I would use `IF..THEN..ELSE` instead of a `SELECT` statement. Finally, `Option Explicit` is your friend

Comment: @Zac, I have multiple cases there. How do you decide when to use Select Case vs If Then?